# calculate $\frac{\partial f }{ \partial \operatorname{Re} (z)} $ from $\frac{\partial f }{ \partial z}$ for meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

$f(z)$ is a meromorphic function, how to derive $\frac{\partial f }{ \partial \operatorname{Re} (z)} $  if the derivative $\frac{\partial f }{ \partial z} $is given?

I guess
$$
\frac{\partial f }{ \partial \operatorname{Re} (z)} =\frac{\partial f }{ \partial z}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial f }{ \partial \operatorname{Im} (z)} =i\frac{\partial f }{ \partial z}
$$

I tested the two equations with a special case $f(z)=(m+ni)z^2$, where $z=a+bi$.
$$
\frac{\partial f }{ \partial \operatorname{Re} (z)} = 2(m+ni)(a+bi)
$$
$$
\frac{\partial f }{ \partial \operatorname{Im} (z)} = 2(-n+mi)(a+bi)
$$

Am I right?

Happy holiday!

Comment: When you write \partial\textrm{Re}(z) instead of \partial\operatorname{Re}(z) then you see $\partial\textrm{Re}(z)$ instead of $\partial\operatorname{Re}(z).$ I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$ and $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. So: $$\frac{\partial f(x+iy)}{\partial x}=\partial_x u(x,y)+i\partial_xv(x,y)=f'(x+iy)$$
Why? Because:
\begin{align}
f'(x+iy) &= \lim_{h\to 0, k=0} \frac{u(x+h,y+k)+iv(x+h,y+k)-u(x,y)-iv(x,y)}{h+ik}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{u(x+h,y)-u(x,y)}{h} +i\frac{v(x+h,y)-v(x,y)}{h}\\
&=\partial_x u(x,y)+i\partial_x v(x,y)
\end{align}
So we may conclude:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \operatorname{Re}{(z)}}=f'(z)
\end{align}
So your guess is right! The second expression you gave is also true. Verify it as I done above.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** With $z=x+iy$ use
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}$$
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}=i\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}\right)$$

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Differentials are much more straightforward. Since $f$ is differentiable,

$$ \mathrm{d} f(z) = f'(z) \mathrm{d} z = f'(z) (\mathrm{d}x + i \, \mathrm{d} y)$$

Assuming $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ are meant to denote the standard tangent vectors in $(x,y)$ coordinates, applying the first sends $\mathrm{d}x \mapsto 1$ and $\mathrm{d}y \mapsto 0$, and the second vice versa, so we get

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(z) = f'(z) (1 + i \cdot 0) = f'(z) $$
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(z) = f'(z) (0 + i \cdot 1) = i f'(z) $$

Assuming $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ means the standard tangent vector in $(z, \bar{z})$-coordinates, we indeed have

$$f'(z) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} f(z)$$

confirming the conjecture.

Comment: Incidentally, I harp on how the partial derivative notation is interpreted not because it's unclear what is meant (the interpretations given in my post are usually always what is intended), but because it is rather uncommon knowledge that the notation is ambiguous. Also, I brought it up because I wanted a lead-in to emphasize how the partial derivative operators act on the basis differentials.